# I'm having a problem when I try to save the data without pictures or images. I get this message: "Empty path name is not legal."

Tags: c#

When I tried to save without an image or picture, I got the error "Empty path name is not legal", but when I saved with an image attached in Picturebox, there was no problem.

This is my code.

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
cmd = new OleDbCommand ("Insert into tbl_idmonitoring (AcctNo, Lastname, Firstname, MI, 
Address, IDStatus, MemStatus, TIN, DateRelease, Picture)values(@AcctNo, @Lastname, @Firstname, 
@MI, @Address, @IDStatus, @MemStatus, @TIN, @DateRelease, @Picture) ", con);
con.Open();
string path = ofd.FileName;
Byte[] imageData;
imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@path); //This line is the "Error"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcctNo", txtAcctno.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLastname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFirstname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MI", txtMI.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDStatus", cmbIDStatus.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemStatus", cmbMemStatus.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIN", txtTIN.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateRelease", dateTimePicker1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", imageData);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Data Successfully Saved!");
Clear();
}
```

Comment: Your path cannot be empty, therefore you need to read an actual picture, or handle the condition in an if clause.

Comment: When `FileName` is empty, `ReadAllBytes` wont work. So make you're `FileName` is not empty, before using `ReadAllBytes`

Comment: So I need to input the path of the database or the path of the picture? Can you give me an example of my code, sir?

Comment: So what's `ofd.FileName`?

Comment: Do you have any examples of save code, sir?

Comment: ofd is OpenFileDialog sir.

Comment: You need to post the code that initializes and shows the OpenFileDialog. Are you handling `DialogResult.Cancel`? While debugging, what is the content of `ofd.FileName`? -- Note that OleDbCommand is also disposable. -- You don't need `con.Close()`, since the connection is declared with a `using` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Like the others said, you definitely need to check the path string. Here's one way you could do that:

```
string path = ofd.FileName;
Byte[] imageData;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
{
    try
    {
        imageData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@path);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (imageData == null)
            imageData = new byte[0];
    }
}
else
{
    //Here you could use a default picture path, assign it to the path variable, and convert it to a byte array.
}
```

**edit: removed something on this line that I didn't intend to leave**

Comment: Is it possible the end of your answer got cut off?

Comment: Thank you Sven, I didn't mean for that to be there.